# Apply Image Assets Path @1x @2x @3x

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, ios9, assets

I'm storing my image assets using the group reference to my actual folder structure.
I get the path to the image, but how can I apply @2x and @3x with the actual file path name?

```
myPath : /Users/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7649D8EA-72A9-4764-9FDB-7BF8EEF59004/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2805AA67-CF88-4284-9A1D-751860A832EZ/app/Interests/ARTS/arts.png

I'm loading it : [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:myPath]
```

In this case, I only load the @1x file. Should I create another method to check the device or any brilliant idea?
Thanks

Comment: as you have suggested in the question, you can check for the device scale and append that with the image name so you can get proper resolution image

Comment: @Pyro, I mean is there any more efficient way to get the correct resolution without checking the device?

Comment: best way will be to check the device/screen scale to get the proper picture , otherwise if you static image resource you can store it in the images.xcassets which manages all this for you

Answer (score 1):

As Pyro said, Xcode actually do this only. You can check with Resources/Images/Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset folder which contain Content.son file. It save image name, size, scale and device type.